# Confusion matrix with KNN in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, confusion-matrix

How do I produce a confusion matrix to see the precision, recall and F score for a KNN model in R? Here's my R code for the KNN model:

```
nn <- knn(train = train.norm.df[, 1:14], test = new.norm.df, cl = train.norm.df[, 3], k = 3)
```

How do I display this model, `nn` in a confusion matrix?

Markdown file: https://rpubs.com/evanmullen36/840780

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do using the `iris` data set which is included with R. First we need training and testing subsets of the data:

```
library(class)
data(iris)

set.seed(42)
idx <- seq(nrow(iris))
train <- unname(unlist(tapply(idx, iris$Species, sample, size=25)))
train <- sort(train)
test <- idx[!idx %in% train]
```

Now you can use the nearest neighbor function:

```
predict <- knn(iris[train, 1:4], iris[test, 1:4], iris$Species[train])
(conftbl <- table(Species=iris$Species[test], Predict=predict))
#             Predict
# Species      setosa versicolor virginica
#   setosa         25          0         0
#   versicolor      0         25         0
#   virginica       0          2        23

Correct <- sum(diag(conftbl))/sum(conftbl) * 100
cat("Percent Correct = ", round(Correct, 2))
# Percent Correct =  97.33
```

Notice that in your example you included a column in both the `train=` and `cl=` arguments (column 3 is in both). That means that you used the class membership to predict the class membership which is circular. If column 3 is the class membership you should use `train = train.norm.df[, c(1:2, 4:14)]` and `test = new.norm.df[, c(1:2, 4:14)]`.

Comment: Just submitted an edit as you posted this. I shared my RMarkdown file is that helps.